# Don't spend too much effort on it

Tags: traduction, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Comment pourrait-on dire *Don't spend too much effort on it* ? Par exemple, dans le contexte où je conseille à un collègue d'essayer une approche particulière, mais sans être sûr que le succès de cette approche est garantie.

Littéralement, je dirais : *ne dépense trop d'effort sur ça*. Mais je doute qu'il s'agit de la meilleure façon de le dire. J'ai considéré aussi *n'y mets pas trop d'effort*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans un registre informel ou familier, on pourrait dire:

> Te casse pas la tête

> Te casse pas la nénette

> Vas-y mollo

> Te fatigue pas trop là-dessus

"*Nénette*" est apparemment une contraction de *comprenette* en argot.

Answer (score 1):

Une traduction quasi littérale de *Don't spend too much effort on it* serait « sans y mettre trop d'énergie ».

- Tu peux essayer mais c'est la peine d'y mettre trop d'énergie.

Des expressions familières ont déjà été données, j'en rajoute juste une qui est assez courante :  « sans se fouler », « [se fouler](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/fouler) » étant familier pour « se donner du mal ».

- Essaye-donc mais sans trop te fouler.